# CSS Grid: grid-column excludes gaps

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm using CSS Grid to achieve the following [image: layout]. This is what I have so far:

```
.collection__wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  column-gap: 20px;
  row-gap: 10px;
}

.collection__instructions {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
```

Is there any way to span the last input's width right from the start of the row up to where the red line is positioned? grid-column: 1 / 3 does not work for me.

Thanks.

Comment: can you share the result you get so far?

Comment: I shared a screenshot of the actual result. I solved it using the following code: `.collect__instructions {   grid-column: 1 / 3;   width: calc(100% + 20px); }`

Answer (score 1):

Grid column exclude the end value, so you have to mention end value + 1

```
.collection__wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  column-gap: 20px;
  row-gap: 10px;
}

.collection__instructions {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}
```

Refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-column.asp) for more info

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually solved it using the following code: `.collect__instructions {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
}`